# Check event target when using document.attachEvent

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling

I have the following code...

```
document.attachEvent("onclick", get_func(obj, "on_body_click", "event_target_here"));
```

I am attaching a global function get_func() to the event `onclick`. get_func() returns reference to a function defined in a function object something like this..

```
function get_func(obj, funcname, params) {
   if(funcname == "check") {
      return obj.checkTarget(params);
   }
}
```

Now  in the function `checkTarget()`, I need to check which DOM object was clicked upon. How can I do this? I understand that I need to send the target of onclick event to the global function somehow.

Can somebody throw some light on this?

Regards

Comment: Am I right in assuming that obj in get_func is supposed to be the object that was clicked on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass the object that was clicked on into the global function, you can modify your event attachment to use the click event's source element to something like this:

```
document.attachEvent("onclick", function(e) { get_func((e || event).srcElement, "on_body_click", "event_target_here") });
```

Then you could pass that object down to the checkTarget function.